How do I prevent duplicate rows in Postgresql while using COUNT and partitions?
first time question asker here and pretty new to SQL. I'm doing a project in postgresql and pgadmin 4 (if that matters) and I'm getting duplicates in my 'title' and 'title_mo_rentals' fields when using COUNT and inserting. Here is my table:
CREATE TABLE detailed_report (  
  rental_id INT PRIMARY KEY
, store_num INT
, rental_year INT
, rental_month VARCHAR(9)
, genre VARCHAR(25)
, genre_mo_rentals INT
, title VARCHAR (50)
, title_mo_rentals INT
, genre_ytd_rentals INT  
);

Here is my code so far:
INSERT INTO detailed_report (
  rental_id
, store_num
, rental_year
, rental_month
, genre
, genre_mo_rentals
, title
, title_mo_rentals
, genre_ytd_rentals
)
SELECT
  r.rental_id
, i.store_id AS store_num
, DATE_PART('year', r.rental_date) AS rental_year
, TO_CHAR(r.rental_date, 'Month') AS rental_month
, cat.name AS genre
, COUNT(r.rental_id) OVER (PARTITION by i.store_id, DATE_PART('year', r.rental_date),  TO_CHAR(r.rental_date, 'YYYY/MM'), cat.name) as genre_mo_rentals
, f.title AS title
, COUNT(r.rental_id) OVER (PARTITION by i.store_id, DATE_PART('year', r.rental_date), TO_CHAR(r.rental_date, 'YYYY/MM'), cat.name, f.title) AS title_mo_rentals
, COUNT(r.rental_id) OVER (PARTITION by i.store_id, DATE_PART('year', r.rental_date), cat.name) AS genre_ytd_rentals
FROM rental r
INNER JOIN inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
INNER JOIN film f ON i.film_id = f.film_id
INNER JOIN film_category fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
INNER JOIN category cat ON fc.category_id = cat.category_id
;

I'm OK with the duplicates in the other fields, but I would like 'title' and 'title_mo_rentals' to only display one row instead and can't seem to find a way to make it happen.
enter image description here
So I've obviously tried using partitions and I've experimented with CTEs but I can't seem to make those work either. I've been scouring the internet for days and trying/failing everything I find. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Do you want to aggregate those 4 rows into a single one? If that's the case you can use GROUP BY.

My goal is for the row duplicates (in my attached image, it's American Circus and Antitrust Tomatoes) to not show up when querying the table. I want each title to only appear in one row per month. Hopefully that makes sense.

There are no "row duplicates" in your image, only duplicates in some columns. Do you wish to remove whole rows? If so which ones? Your task will be simple once your formulate the goal clearly. Currently, it's ambiguous. If you are having difficulties expressing that, try providing sample rows, the current result and the desired result - as text in the question, not as image. Ideally, add a fiddle to work with. Typically, the best solution is not to duplicate rows in the query to begin with.

Don't use images, provide data as tables with text. Also add the expected result.

Why not use DISTINCT ON? You can do: INSERT ... SELECT DISTINCT ON (rental_id, rental_year, rental_month) * FROM ( <your-SELECT-here> ) x ORDER BY rental_id, rental_year, rental_month.
